# Wrapping a DLL into my own DLL to Modify the Values Passed to it

Tags: c++, c, dll

Im trying to Wrap the DLL "dbghelp.dll", mainly the function "ImageNtHeader", into my own DLL, that i can then place it into Notepad++, so it uses my Wrapped dbghelp.dll, instead of the Original Windows XP DLL.

Im aware, there is a thing called "KnownDLLs", but i already worked my way around that, by deleting the corresponding Registry values, and i can confirm that this works.

I would like to avoid using LoadLibraryA or simmilar, everytime my Function gets called, as that would likely majorly slow down the Programms depending on those DLL Calls. I also do not want to Embed the Original DLL, i just want to redirect the cal, if that makes sense, id also preferrably like to avoid using Detours, as that seems suboptimal, and cus it surely must be possible to just redirect to a specific adress of a same function(2x ImageNtHeader) in two different DLLs/Implementations (mydbghelp.dll and windowsdbghelp.dll)

The Final-Final End Goal (not entirely important here as far as i can see) is Comparable to, but not the same as WINE from Linux. Essentially wanting to Adapt new DLL commands from as Example Vista to the older Windows XP ones, but before i can do that, i'll have to manage to redirect the original calls too. Could also be simmilar to Gamehacking in a way? Redirecting and Modifying DLL Calls?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express, as my Target is Windows XP, and this is the last Properly Supported/Working IDE for it.

I got it that far, that if i just `return 0;`, Notepad++ spits out some errors about Plugins not being Compatible, but as soon as i code it to call the original function, compile it, and try to run Notepad++ again, it immediatly Crashes..

I got this following Code (Which Crashes Notepad++)

ImageNtHeader.cpp

```
#include "ImageNtHeader.h"

#include <DbgHelp.h>

PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS MyImageNtHeader(PVOID Base)
{
    return ImageNtHeader(Base);
}
```

ImageNtHeader.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS MyImageNtHeader(PVOID Base);
```

FunctionRename.def

```
EXPORTS
    ImageNtHeader = MyImageNtHeader
```

I expect this to Work Flawlessly, but since im New to this DLL and Header and .DEF buisness, i might be overlooking something. I tried googling, and using AI, but i got nothing more than this together.

Comment: "as soon as I code it to call the original function it immediately crashes"... with a stackoverflow, because it's not calling the original function, it's calling itself.  Because you used the original import library when building your DLL, it looks for the function inside "dbghelp.dll", which is your replacement.  Don't call LoadLibrary+GetProcAddress every time your function gets called, but only once, and save the function pointer.

Comment: A much simpler approach though is to modify the Notepad++ executable to import from "myghelp.dll" instead of "dbghelp.dll".  Learn how to put forwarding exports in the DEF file.

Comment: Not sure about later ones, but Visual Studio 2015 Express can target WinXP as well, when setting `Platform Toolset = Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)`.